# Android Camera Intent: how to get full sized photo?

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I am using intent to launch camera:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getParent().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

and using:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
photoImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
photoImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But it is only a thumbnail, how do I get the full bitmap? I know I can use my own Activity and use:

```
Camera.PictureCallback()
```

But is there anyway to do it using Intent?

Thanks!

edit:

I also tried:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
}
```

It works for photo selected from gallery, but for camera intent, data.getData() returns null.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

To get full sized camera image you should point camera to save picture in temporary file, like:

```
    private URI mImageUri;

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo;
    try
    {
        // place where to store camera taken picture
        photo = this.createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
        photo.delete();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Can't create file to take picture!");
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Please check SD card! Image shot is impossible!", 10000);
        return false;
    }
    mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
    //start camera intent
    activity.startActivityForResult(this, intent, MenuShootImage);

private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
{
    File tempDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    tempDir=new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/.temp/");
    if(!tempDir.exists())
    {
        tempDir.mkdirs();
    }
    return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
}
```

Then after image capture intent finished to work - just grab your picture from `imageUri` using following code:

```
public void grabImage(ImageView imageView)
{
    this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageUri, null);
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try
    {
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mImageUri);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to load", e);
    }
}


//called after camera intent finished
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    //MenuShootImage is user defined menu option to shoot image
    if(requestCode==MenuShootImage && resultCode==RESULT_OK) 
    {
       ImageView imageView;
       //... some code to inflate/create/find appropriate ImageView to place grabbed image
       this.grabImage(imageView);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

**P.S.** Code need to be revised with respect to new security restriction applied in Android M - [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html): `mImageUri` has to be packed with `FileProvider`

Comment: I tried it, the uri is file:///sdcard/.temp/picture19010.jpg and I used ImageView's setImageUri(), but it does not work, is the path correct, or do I need something to make the uri recognizable by imageview?

Comment: @barmaley I'm thankful you solved hzxu's problem, but I'm confused by your answer.  That code doesn't work as-is.  Any chance you can reformat and explain how 'grabImage' fits into the onActivityResult process?  Thanks!

Comment: @shanabus look more code above - I have added onActivityResult()

Comment: Just want to point out that the important line above is `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);` see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE for the elusive documentation on this behavior.

Comment: @barmaley if i am saving the image permanently on the SD card. will i get the full sized image, or should i compulsorily use temp files? saving the image on the SD card is all that matters right, not whether its temp/permanent?

Comment: Minor corrections for this line: `Toast.makeText(activity, "Please check SD card!...`. Toast does not take msecs parameter but rather a flag LENGTH_LONG or LENGTH_SHORT. Furthermore the ".show()" at the end is forgotten. Nothing very important but just to keep it clean.

Comment: I've tried this solution but the rsult of the image is an error like this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=188, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.ketanolab.lbc/com.ketanolab.lbc.Robototal}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What is MenuShootImage?

Comment: @MarianaHernandez `MenuShootImage` is requestcode this code will be returned in `onActivityResult()` when the activity exits. In this particular case some prefefined `int` which need to be `>0`

Comment: What about now with FileProvider?? Coz all this will not be working on Android 7

Comment: It's amazing I've tried many solutions & only this worked for me! Thx! @ShikharMathur I just combined @barmaley's solution with this one (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/1827488) to make `FileProvider` work. The config details for `FileProvider` in the docs are lacking & this post filled in the blanks which worked 1st try. You must check if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > M` when using `FileProvider.getUriForFile(...)` otherwise must continue to use `Uri.fromFile(...)`

Comment: I tried this and got android.os.FileUriExposedException.

Answer (score 44):

**Open Camera and save image into some specific directory**

```
private String pictureImagePath = "";
private void openBackCamera() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
    File file = new File(pictureImagePath);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);               
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
}
```

Handle Image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
    File imgFile = new  File(pictureImagePath);
        if(imgFile.exists()){        
       Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
       ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
       myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: After searching the internet for 24 hours, this was the only code that did what I want. The only problem now is, it is showing the image in landscape mode even if I take it in Portrait mode.

Comment: Also the only one that is working .....i really  don't understand why such simple task should be so much complicated

Comment: Remember you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. The code in this answer is from https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Good one Simple and understandable.Others have done so much complicated codes

Comment: People really complicated the whole thing with long answers . One thing I'm facing after every click I come back to activity, can't I click multiple images together. can idea how to do? and thanks for this great code.

Comment: cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri); this line prevents me to hit accept taken image button

Comment: @MaksimKniazev I experience the same, it appears that for API > 24, we need to use getUriForFile as documented here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Comment: Yeah, this worked by Android doc example which is similar does not. Thanks +1

Comment: Please update this, its always in landscape mode. Me and many others need a fix!

Comment: @LukasNiessen hi, have you resolved the issue with landscape mode?

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is an old question and it has an accepted answer,
I would like to share my solution.
In this case you don't have to create a temporary file.
Additionally we **creating a chooser which offers to user both: take a picture with the camera or pick an existing one from a gallery.**

```
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent);
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.chooseaction));
    Intent[] intentArray = {cameraIntent};
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
    startActivityForResult(chooser, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

and here we retrieving results:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // todo use appropriate resultCode in your case
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getData() != null) {
            // this case will occur in case of picking image from the Gallery,
            // but not when taking picture with a camera
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());

                // do whatever you want with the Bitmap ....           

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // this case will occur when taking a picture with a camera
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                    null, "date_added DESC");
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
                String photoPath = uri.toString();
                cursor.close();
                if (photoPath != null) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
                }
            }

            if (bitmap == null) {
                // for safety reasons you can
                // use thumbnail if not retrieved full sized image
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }
            // do whatever you want with the Bitmap ....
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: really nice way, because it doesn't require readExternalStorage permission. Also native camera or gallery picker is comfortable way for user to complete action

Comment: This and many other answers return last gallery image for camera instead of a camera shot. Tested in API 23 emulator and API 21 device. Uri references to a path different to an original photo. Also data == null.

Comment: Trying this out: If I select gallery everything works as described here. But if I select camera the resultCode == REQUEST_CANCELLED.

Answer (score 2):

I also used the answer from Vicky but I had to save the uri to a bundle to avoid loss of it on orientation change. So if you don't get a result from your intent after tilting the device it might be because your uri did not survive the orientation change.

```
static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_REQUEST = 1;
static final String ARG_CURRENT_PIC_URI = "CURRENT_PIC_URI";


String pictureImagePath = folderName + "/" + imageFileName;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), pictureImagePath);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

mCurrentPicUri = outputFileUri.getPath();

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_REQUEST);
```

Activity Result code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
  {
    File imgFile = new  File(mCurrentPicUri);
    // do something with your image
    // delete uri
    mCurrentPicUri = "";
  }
}
```

save the uri to the bundle:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  // save uri to bundle
  outState.putString(ARG_CURRENT_PIC_URI, mCurrentPicUri);
}
```

retrieve it from your saved bundle during on create:

```
if (bundle.containsKey(ARG_CURRENT_PIC_URI))
  mCurrentPicUri = bundle.getString(ARG_CURRENT_PIC_URI);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `onActivityResult`'s data. It took me many hours to test different solutions. A camera saves a picture (even if you don't set permissions for camera and card reading in AndroidManifest), but then `onActivityResult` returns `data == null` and `MediaStore` returns wrong path. In these solutions you simply get last gallery image, not your photo.

```
private Uri photoUri;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    ...
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (photoUri != null) {
                image.setImageURI(photoUri);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void showCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        photoUri = null;
        if (file != null) {
            photoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File storageDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    // File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".jpg", storageDir);
}
```

Comment: Really no upvotes? This is the best solution compared to all...

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE, thank you very much! I am glad that this solution helped you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok Time to pay back.
So u have your permissions on Mainfest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and u also have your provider meta-data

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

One missed detail is (android:authorities applicationId) u need to add your own app package name.
So u have `xml` file under `res` folder as we mentioned on `manifest` and under it u have created `file_paths` with ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

we are done with copy paste part 1. Now on our activity above `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` define these beauties

```
    val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String
    var cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

U might like to have a look at original resource but missing details as usual Android Developers : [link](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

An other missing detail is `packageName + ".fileprovider",` be carefull u need to give your own package name if u allredy have method.

```
// org android developers
    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    ex.message
                    null
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        packageName + ".fileprovider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`createImageFile` function

```
 // org android developers
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File = this!!.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }

    }
```

**Testing**.
call your `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` method with onClick event, make sure permissions are permitted

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
var  mBitmap_org = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                //Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath)
                Uri.fromFile(File(currentPhotoPath))
            );
        //mImg_display?.setImageBitmap(mBitmap_org)
}
    }
```

Don't check data we will get it through imagePath. If u are checking `Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath)` make sure it's `Uri.fromFile(File(currentPhotoPath))`

Now u have your bitmap, time to spend other hours/days how to resize decode, save.

There is also a method to save tokken image, maybe you could help me to see where should I put it, if I need tokken image to be save on gallery

```
  // org android developers
    private fun galleryAddPic() {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).also { mediaScanIntent ->
            val f = File(currentPhotoPath)
            mediaScanIntent.data = Uri.fromFile(f)
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**API Level 29**

I tried the accepted answer, but both `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` used in the accepted answer and `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` used in a subsequent answer are deprecated in API level 29. So is the `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` used in the third answer deprecated in API level 29. The following code (in Kotlin) stores the full image in `MediaStore` as shown in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56990305/13616480) to a different question and doesn't rely on the `FileProvider`:

```
    var imageUri: Uri? = null

    fun takePhoto(view: View?) {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "myimage.jpg")
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST)
    }
```

Comment: But `MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH` deprecated too.

Comment: Try `imageUri = contentResolver.insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
 }) 
`
This still works for me as of API Level 33.

Answer (score 0):

To capture maximum picture size from camera, i hope these simple steps will be quite useful

```
 public static Camera mCamera;

Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
  parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
  mSizePicture1 = supportedSizes.get(0);
  int cameraSize = supportedSizes.size();
  mSizePicture2 = supportedSizes.get(cameraSize - 1);

    if (mSizePicture1.height < mSizePicture2.height)
       mSizePicture = supportedSizes.get(cameraSize - 1);
    else
       mSizePicture = supportedSizes.get(0);

parameters.setPictureSize(mSizePicture.width, mSizePicture.height);
```

Here, the supported size of the each mobile is taken, from that which size is maximum that is fixed as picture size to capture.