# Taking multiple photos using MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am interested to capture the multiple images once the camera is open through an intent MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA.

I’ve found the answer to the similar problem ([How to take multiple photos before dismissing camera intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent) ) with some solution to use a ContentObserver.

I understand that I will have to register the ContentObserver on the MediaStore content provider and then query the media store to retrieve the information about newly added photos from my application.

Is there any way to designate the taken photos that they relate to my application? Maybe passing some extra parameter with intent such as [EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quite surprising that nobody has answered this question in the last 4 years. I am facing the same problem now.