# Android take multiple images and process them on return

Tags: android, camera

I've successfully made an app that takes a photo via `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);` and I get the full size image in the `onActivityResult`.
But this approach takes a single photo.
I've investegated [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent) link.
By adding `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`
camera takes multiple images, but after the user presses the back button, I need to process the taken.

How to process captured images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to process captured images?

Do not delegate your picture-taking to another app. Instead, you do it in your own app, such as via the camera APIs. Or, use your existing `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);` code and just call it again and again until the user stops taking pictures.

`INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` just opens a camera app. You do not control where the images get stored, and the camera app does not have to store the images anywhere that your app can access them. It also does not have to tell you where it stored the images.

Comment: I'm now going with second approach, as taking photos is not the app's primary feature.I can think of another approach which is a beat nasty: in the mean while of ``startActivityForResult`` I get the systemsCurrentMillis and also start a thread.the thread checks the images photos repeatedly which there creation timeinMillis is bigger than the saved time in Millis and processes them.this thread stops in the ``onResultActivity`` @commonsWare what about this approach? I'm asking because I don't want to develop my own camera app.tnx.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `INTENT_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will only take one picture. If your "mean while" refers to `INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`, you do not know where the images will be stored, and you may not have access to that location anyway.