# Capture multiple images via Camera

Tags: android, camera

I want to capture multiple images at once use front camera. After research I know I can use intent to achieve my expect with action **MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA**
 as I found this :

[How to take multiple photos before dismissing camera intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent)

But the answer accepted do not tell how to use **ContentObserver**.

Can you help give me a code example for this?

I also found a good library can capture multiple images but this lib do not support front camera ( I need front camera to capture selfie )

https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker

Is there any lib like **poly picker** which support front camera ?

Comment: "I know I can use intent to achieve my expect with action MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA as I found this" -- that answer is incorrect. All this `Intent` action does, at most, is start a camera app. There is no requirement for that app to store pictures in a place where you can reach them, let alone via a `ContentObserver`. There is no requirement for that app to allow access to the front-facing camera. If you specifically need to capture multiple front-facing camera images, use the camera APIs directly and take them yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks for your information. You are my idol on SO. I am very happy when receive the comment from you.