# How to restrict user to upload at most 5 image in android?

Tags: android

I am using android java. And I am trying to let user to upload photos to my application at most 5 images. I am using this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
SELECT_PICTURE);
```

with On Activity Result.

Comment: so keep track of how many images they have uploaded

Comment: Nah, i wanna let them select multiple image up to 5 at once. I mean they can select 5 photo image at once but cant select 6.

Comment: You can't enforce that through 3rd party apps because you don't know which app will be chosen. You'd have to make your own picker or tell them that 5 is too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take multiple photos before dismissing camera intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent)

Comment: Thanks all. Guess I have to make only like what you guy advice

Answer (score 0):

Well more code would be nice, but if I were you I would add the following basic solution:
create an ArrayList of Images and store those.

```
List<Bitmap> uploadedImageList = new ArrayList<>();
```

in the onActivitResult():

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK
   && requestCode == yourRequestCode){
  //transform to bitmap
  //add bitmap to your list
  }
```

thank you can use if(arrayList.size() == 5){...do whatever...}

**UPDATE**
I think I miss read the question, he wants user to upload 5 images at one:
[How to take multiple photos before dismissing camera intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent)

Comment: This only can make user to upload one photo per upload, right ?

Comment: I wanna let user to upload multiple photo at most 5 at once .

Comment: I think you need this to allow user take multiple images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent