# How to take multiple images using camera in android

Tags: android, camera

I need a camera that allows me take multiple pictures at once and then select one. Others may or may not be stored on the device. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647371/how-to-take-multiple-photos-before-dismissing-camera-intent). I can take multiple images but how to select one and use it in my app? I read the documentation related to camera2 but its hard to understand without any practical example.I also tried [these](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager), but an isolated snippet won't help.
Any example related to the use of burst camera would help.

I do not expect a full code, but any directions on how to proceed? Is it possible to display the picture thumbnails as an when they are clicked on the camera screen itself. I'll need to have the bitmap of the image selected.

I can rephrase any part of the question if not clear.

Comment: can you add code that you tried

Comment: I've tried the code in the examples as it is. If you're not talking about the code apart from the camera action?

Answer (score 6):

**Try this**

you can Call your second `startActivityForResult()` from the `onActivityResult()` you get from your first `startActivityForResult()`.

**like this by this code you can get 10 pic**

```
public int PIC_CODE=0;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  

        // get new image here like this
       if(PIC_CODE<10){
            // add new requset of picture like this
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            PIC_CODE++;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement your own camera to take multiple pictures. Create a class with surface view and implements `SurfaceView.Callback`. Please check out my library which will implement the same.

https://github.com/SripadRaj/BurstCamera

Comment: A Readme with previews would be great in that repo!

Comment: @MarcelHofgesang Sure will work on it to update it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I am looking forward to it