# How to capture multiple image from Camera

Tags: android

```
private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
       if(activities.size()>0) {
           startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
       }
       else
       {

       }
    }
```

This is my code i am  trying to capture image i want capture image multiple pic but this code is not working can any one suggest me how take multiple capture image in android

Comment: "i am trying to capture image" -- that code brings up a compatible camera app. Whether the user takes a photo or not is up to the user, and you are not told whether the user takes zero, one, or several photos.

Comment: please suggest me how to capture multiple pic from  camera

Comment: That is covered in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429837/how-to-take-multiple-images-using-camera-in-android).