# I want to save images in gallery and share with external application

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, adapter

I design one app where I am displaying image using recyclerView.
I am not clicking image from camera, its downloded from json api.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.bjp.app.bjpapp.MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_design.xml
this layout file designed for the component views and this file attaching with recyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/share"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/download"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/downward"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Data.java (Modal class.)

this is my getter and setter class file code.

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String imgUrl;

    public Data(int id, String imgUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }
}
```

Adapter class file code is here 
Image_Adaper.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data> data;
    private Context context;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    String url1;
    String filepath;
    public ImageAdapter(List<Data> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_design,parent,false);
        return new ImageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data data1=data.get(position);
         url1=data1.getImgUrl();
        ImageView imageView=holder.imageView;
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(data1.getImgUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ImageButton share,download;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            share=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
            download=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);

            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position=getAdapterPosition();
                    Data data2=data.get(position);
                    // i want to share a image with social sites
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Product id "+data2+"  btn working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"download btn working"+url1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

I am attaching the mail layout screenshot for more understanding.

The image should be downloaded on click of the download button. 
and Image should be shareable to social apps. 
I tried some code but it is not working. 
Please, guys, help me to find solutions. 
Thank you in advance. 
[please find the attachment of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa8eh.jpg)

Comment: if you google it, lots of example available.

Comment: What did you try to save and share the image? I see no code done inside OnClickListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Save image on SD card with its original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579084/android-save-image-on-sd-card-with-its-original-size)

Comment: String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images_1");
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

Comment: @HemantParmar ,  No I am not capturing image from camera.  I am downloading image from api and displaying it on recyclerView .

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link for download or save image from image view

[Save image from ImageView to device gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718374/save-image-from-imageview-to-device-gallery)

For Sharing image foloww below link

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html