# taken from android camera image original resolution

Tags: android, android-image

This code gives me image taken from android camera ,however,its size and resolution format of the thumnail.

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

How can I get the original image with the original size and resolution
Thank you

Comment: Post the code relevant to when you take the image with your camera up to you do `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); `

Comment: Post your `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

this code gives you only thumnail image.To get the original image u need to use `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` which image saved there. (Code is something like this)

```
 File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

For more information take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Temp File in externalCacheDir and put the URI in your Intent which starts the camera, after image shooting the image is stored in that file.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File tempCaptureFile = ImageAccessor.createTempFile(getActivity(), TEMP_CAPTURE_FILE_NAME);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tempCaptureFile));

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

ImageAccessor is just a helper class to create a File in externalCacheDir.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`

this line only return thumbnal image reffer bellow link

[android camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo)