# Can't receive Intent.extras() from Camera after making a photo

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-bundle

I found it's a common problem with capturing photo and receiving full size photo instead of thumbnail (according to: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html ). Taking photo and receiving thumbnail is easy, but rest of tutorial seems to be uncomplete and not working. Anyone resolved it in easy way?

```
public class TakePhoto extends Activity{

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.take_photo);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    dispatchTakePictureIntent();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.i("ASD", ex.toString());
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

}

```
04-25 18:01:14.239  17281-17281/com.(package).bazaar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.(package).bazaar, PID: 17281
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.(package).bazaar/com.(package).bazaar.TakePhoto}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3626)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3669)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at com.klangstudios.bazaar.TakePhoto.onActivityResult(TakePhoto.java:46)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3622)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3669)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: And what is the exact problem? Please clarify.

Comment: @rasmeta sorry, I forgot to add LogCat log. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not expect `data` to be `null` there. However, there should not be any extras on that `Intent`. You only look for the `"data"` extra if you are *not* specifying `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. If you are specifying `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you go get the photo from the path that you provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and you ignore the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`.

With regards to the `null` `data` `Intent` itself, that may be something peculiar to the camera app that you are using. Please bear in mind that using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` means that you are relying upon a third-party app to take the picture, and third-party apps can have bugs.

Comment: That's it! Instead of taking extras() from Bundle I put: Uri uri = fileUri;
            Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(myImg);

Comment: Just to clarify, ```fileUri``` you're using is a global variable that receives the value of ```Uri.fromFile(photoFile));```

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Android Camera Intent: how to get full sized photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo)

Although what is doing is reading the file you create before launching camera intent, not reading `data`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled hours on the same problem than "jean d'arme", except that I was seeking to get URI and not Bitmap. To spare other users this waste of time, I will highlight the clarifications of "jean d'arme" and "Felipe Augusto" that helped me solved the error, with the below steps :

1) Add a global variable in your class

```
private Uri uri;
```

2) Use this variable to get the content of photoURI inside dispatchTakePictureIntent()

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        {...}

        if (photoFile != null) {
            uri = photoURI;
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Use this Uri in the onActivityResult method for whatever task you aim to

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Perform any task using uri
        //For example set this URI to fill an ImageView like below
        this.imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

I hope this highlight will help some of you !