# Picture taken from the camera is blurred

Tags: android, camera

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(intent,Constantes.REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

result

```
Bundle bundle =data.getExtras();
 Bitmap bit = bundle.getParcelable("data");
```

Comment: You are only getting the thumbnail from this, try checking out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo

Comment: Can be caused if you move device, from incorrect focus or from dirty lens.  You can use MagicalTakePhoto library.