# save full size image android studio

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, image-size

I'm trying to save full-size image on database but the app keep saving image smallest than the original that I took with the camera. Here is the `onActivityResult` method:

```
case TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST_DOCUMENTO:
        case TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST_INFRACCION:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Avatar camera mode was canceled.
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                // Took a picture, use the downsized camera image provided by
                // default
                Bitmap cameraPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                if (cameraPic != null) {
                    try {


                        saveAvatar(cameraPic, requestCode);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "saveAvatar() with camera image failed.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;


private void saveAvatar(Bitmap avatar, int pRequestCode) {
        String strAvatarFilename = "avatar.jpg";
        String sPreferenceFoto = GAME_PREFERENCES_AVATAR;
        String sNumeroActa = (new ActaConstatacionRules(this)).getNextNumeroActa();
        int _idButton = 0;
        switch (pRequestCode) {
        case TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST_LICENCIA:
            strAvatarFilename = sNumeroActa + "_licencia.jpg";
            sPreferenceFoto = CURRENT_ACTA_FOTO_LICENCIA;
            _idButton = R.id.ImageButton_Licencia;
            break;
        case TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST_DOCUMENTO:
            strAvatarFilename = sNumeroActa + "_documento.jpg";
            sPreferenceFoto = CURRENT_ACTA_FOTO_DOCUMENTO;
            _idButton = R.id.ImageButton_Documento;
            break;
        case TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST_INFRACCION:
            strAvatarFilename = sNumeroActa + "_infraccion.jpg";
            sPreferenceFoto = CURRENT_ACTA_FOTO_INFRACCION;
            _idButton = R.id.ImageButton_Infraccion;
            break;
        default:
            Utilities.ShowToast(this, "Seleccion de Imagen Invalida");
            return;
        }
        File image = null;
        try {

            File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            image = new File(sdCardDirectory, strAvatarFilename);
            FileOutputStream outStream;

            try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                avatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
                /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Avatar compression and save failed.", e);
        }
 strAvatarFilename));
        if (image == null)
            return;
        Uri imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo = Uri.fromFile(image);

        Editor editor = mCurrenActaSettings.edit();
        editor.putString(sPreferenceFoto, imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo.getPath());
        editor.commit();

        // Update the settings screen
        ImageButton avatarButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(_idButton);
        String strAvatarUri = mCurrenActaSettings.getString(sPreferenceFoto, RESOURCE_SIN_FOTO);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(strAvatarUri);
        avatarButton.setImageURI(null); // Workaround for refreshing an
                                        // ImageButton, which tries to cache the
                                        // previous image Uri. Passing null
                                        // effectively resets it.
        avatarButton.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
```

I need to know how to save the (for example) 600 x 600 image size but without losing quality, now its saving 200 x 100 but I don't know why.

Comment: You didn't post the code that sends the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, but the bottom line is that if you get back `getExtras().get("data")`, it is a tiny thumbnail. The full size image is written to file, and you can read it when needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, sorry for the delay, I understand what you saying but how do I get the full size image in order to set the imageview and saveit with the full size in database.

Comment: I put the link to the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449092/192373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public File saveBitmapToFile(File file) {
    try {

        // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inSampleSize = 6;
        // factor of downsizing the image

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        inputStream.close();
        inputStream = null;

        int originalWidth = options.outWidth;
        int originalHeight = options.outHeight;

        if (originalWidth > 0) {

            int reqWidth = 600;
            int reqHeight = (reqWidth * originalHeight) / originalWidth;
            if (reqHeight >= 600)
                reqHeight = 600;
            Log.d("new image ", "getDropboxIMGSize: " + reqHeight + "    " + 
 reqWidth);
            // decode full image pre-resized
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // calc rought re-size (this is no exact resize)
            options.inSampleSize = Math.max(originalWidth / reqWidth, originalHeight 
 / reqHeight);
            // decode full image
            Bitmap roughBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, 
 options);

            // calc exact destination size
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, roughBitmap.getWidth(), 
 roughBitmap.getHeight());
            RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            float[] values = new float[9];
            m.getValues(values);

            // resize bitmap
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(roughBitmap,
                    (int) (roughBitmap.getWidth()*values[0]),
            (int) (roughBitmap.getHeight()*values[4]),true);

            // override resized bitmap image
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
        }
        return file;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Image", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
  }
```