# Android Camera Intent only returns landscape image

Tags: android, image

I've followed Androids tutorial on how to take a full-size picture. (https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java - The part "Save the full-size photo")

The resulting image I get is however ALWAYS in landscape mode, also if I take in Portrait mode. Also no difference whether I use the front or back camera.

I've also tried many answers from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo) and the ones that work also only give a landscape image (e.g. the answer from Vicky).

---

I must have the image in portrait mode though, how can I achieve this?

Comment: "The resulting image I get is however ALWAYS in landscape mode, also if I take in Portrait mode" -- how are you determining if the image is landscape? Are you loading it in `ImageView` and looking at the result? If so, how are you loading the image into the `ImageView`? Or are you determining this by some other means?

Comment: `Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath); bigimage.setImageBitmap(photo);` So yes, by an ImageView.

Comment: Use an image-loading library, such as Glide, Picasso, or coil. Or, use `ExifInterface` to read the orientation tag, then rotate your image before displaying it (or rotate the `ImageView`, if you prefer).

Comment: Try using this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066265/10752962,
it worked for me well..