# How to get high resolution picture from intents in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, onactivityresult

I am using Intents to open the camera and take images from it. but the image gets pixelated. Is there any proper way of taking **high-resolution** images and saving them to the gallery?

**Here is my Intent code**

```
if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
```

**Here is my onActivityResult Code**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {

                //TODO: Work on Camera picture

                button = false;
                sharetest.setText("Share");
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449092/6280156

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Camera Intent: how to get full sized photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo)