# When saving a photo from the camera, the quality of the image deteriorates

Tags: java, android, android-camera, save-image

Code to call the camera

```
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                                    imagePickerLauncher.launch(cameraIntent);
                                }
```

The code that saves the image

```
    private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
        if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        String fileName = "MyImage_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1080, 1920);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()/options.inSampleSize, bitmap.getHeight()/options.inSampleSize, true);
            if (resizedBitmap != null) {
                resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

            }
            fos.close();
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[] { image.getAbsolutePath() },
                    null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The image is stored in the gallery but in very poor quality.

I experimented with different quality values ​​in the compress argument and format but it didn't help

The image I receive has an extension of 187x250
[image: The image I receive has an extension of 187x250]

Comment: You seem to be resizing and compressing the image, no wonder the quality deteriorates. Btw, it might help if you'd provide some example of how much it deteriorates, e.g. an original image (along with infos like format and dimensions) and an image resulting from your code.

Comment: @Thomas I edited my question with a link to the image I get
I will also give a link to a photo I took on the standard camera application
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q9ICBQRtQYxlPqFORFpkLBrCAQvl0KSf/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Camera Intent: how to get full sized photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448856/android-camera-intent-how-to-get-full-sized-photo)

Comment: I don't see any quality issues in that 187x250px image. Of course your camera would be able to capture more details and smoother edges but for that small size it looks fine.

Comment: @Thomas in the gallery, the image is displayed with really poor quality and, by the way, it does not allow zooming, that is, neither reducing nor increasing, on the screen of my phone (I think and not only on mine) it looks like pixel art

Comment: @Thomas I need an image in higher magnification and with normal quality
So it looks as if it is good for its extension, but still, this result does not suit me

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your problem so let me try to rephrase: 1) you're taking an image captured by the camera which has a higher resolution, 2) you're resizing the image to be smaller (like your 187x250 example) 3) you're displaying that resized image full screen on a phone which normally has a HD screen, right? If that's the case then yes, the image will look very pixelated as step 2 loses a lot of image information - so resize to a resolution closer to HD.