# Image is saved twice

Tags: android

I am using the following intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

Basically i am using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent to invoke the camera and save the taken image into the specified uri.

It works but at the same time the image is also saved with the default name.

Thus once i have snapped the picture, it is saved twice, both in the uri and in the default path and name.

How do i ensure that it is only saved in the specified uri?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: dont `putExtra` and get the image from the default path and name!

Comment: But my intention is each time an picture is taken using this app, the picture should be replaced. That's the reason. Is it feasible to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the ID or Absolute path of the gallery last image. And delete it.

It can be done like that:

```
/**
 * Gets the last image id from the media store
 * @return
 */
private int getLastImageId(){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::id " + id);
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::path " + fullPath);
        imageCursor.close();
        return id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And to remove the file:

```
private void removeImage(int id) {
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[]{ Long.toString(id) } );
}
```

This code was based on the post: [Deleting a gallery image after camera intent photo taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken)

Comment: Appreciate that answer, do you know if this is a common work around?

Comment: @ChrisConway I'm not sure if it is the best way. But I believe that when you use the default Camera Intent the image will always be saved into gallery. Another solution is not use this Intent, you can create your own camera SurfaceView.

Comment: Yeah, or like @SherifelKhatib said, just save it to the default directory.