# Get Path and Filename from Camera intent result

Tags: android, camera, android-intent, uri, image

I want to make a picture with the camera intent and save it to the default DCIM folder. Then I want to get the path/filename where the picture is stored.

I am trying it with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

With this code, the camera opens and after I have taken one picture it closes and saves the picture to the default image folder (usually /dcim/camera or sdcard/dcim/camera...)

but how can I get the path and filename of the taken picture now?
I have tried almost everything in `onActivityResult`
I tried

```
String result = data.getData();
```

and

```
String result = data.getDataString();
```

and

```
String result = data.toURI();
```

and

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

etc.

I researched the last two days to find a solution for this, there are many articles on the web and on stackoverflow but nothing works.
I don't want a thumbnail, I only want the path (uri?) to the image that the camera has taken.

Thank you for any help

EDIT:
When I try:

```
path=Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/test.jpg";
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

it does not store the image as test.jpg but with the normal image name 2011-10-03.....jpg (but that is ok too, i only need the path to the image, it does not matter what the name is).

Best regards

**EDIT Again**

```
path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
File file = new File(path,"test111111111.jpg");
try {
file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

When I try this, it stores the image to the right folder and with the given name (e.g. test111111.jpg).
But how can I get the filepath now in onActivityResult?

Comment: you allready know the path... since you create your file. you can keep the file or the path as a member variable of your Activity

Answer (score 6):

The picture will be stored twice, first on gallery folder, and after on the file you especified on putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, path) method.

You can obtain the last picture taken doing that:

```
/**
 * Gets the last image id from the media store
 * @return
 */
private int getLastImageId(){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::id " + id);
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::path " + fullPath);
        imageCursor.close();
        return id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This sample was based on post: [Deleting a gallery image after camera intent photo taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken)

Comment: Hey , This code works on samsung tab but doesn't work on lenovo and i-ball tab, is there any other solution ?????

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this in onActivityResult()

```
if(requestCode==CAMERA_CAPTURE)
    {

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {
                String picturePath =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA));
               Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(picturePath);

            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            File out = new File(picturePath);
            try 
            {
                mOriginal = decodeFile(out);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            mSelected.setImageBitmap(mOriginal);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` you can pass an extra [`MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) as the `URI` of the file where you want to save the picture.

Here is a simple example:

```
   File file = new File(path);
   Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

   Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

   startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

**EDIT:** I just tried on my device and `file.createNewFile()` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your quick reply, but it doesn't work as expected. I will explain above.

Comment: a silly question maybe... have you added the permission in the Manifest? android.permission.CAMERA? yes..it can work without permission some times

Comment: yes, I added the permission. I just need to know the path to the picture that the camera has saved. and i know that the path is the default picture folder, so actually i only need the file name or the path to the latest picture taken. i am looking two days for a solution.