# How to get a Uri object from Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

On a certain tap event, I ask the user to add an image. So I provide two options:

1. To add from gallery.
2. To click a new image from camera.

My aim is to keep a list of URIs related to those images.

If the user chooses gallery, then I get the image URI (which is quite simple). But if they choose camera, then after taking a picture, I get the Bitmap object of that picture.

Now how do I convert that Bitmap object to URI, or in other words, how can I get the relative `Uri` object of that bitmap object?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636697/get-path-and-filename-from-camera-intent-result

Comment: some of the code is pretty much hardcoded.
I don't want to hard code the file name of the image.
And not necessarily the image is saved in the DCIM folder..

Answer (score 58):

I have same problem in my project, so i follow the simple method ([click here](http://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/android-getting-image-uri-from-bitmap/)) to get Uri from bitmap.

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: `Images.Media.insertImage` is now `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` Second thing you need to remember to add this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: It return null path in android 6.0

Comment: Two marshmallow devices, Motorola `returns path` but Samsung `returns null`. Any help?

Comment: how to I delete this inserted bitmap file from storage ?

Comment: @AnandSavjani did you fix it?

Comment: @MajedAl-Moqbeli yes I fixed but now i don't know that exact code

Comment: this seems to save the bitmap. is there a way to get the uri from the bitmap object without having to save to file?

Answer (score 7):

```
Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
```

the line mentioned above create a thumbnail using bitmap, that may consume some extra space in your android device.

This method may help you to get the Uri from bitmap without consuming some extra memory.

```
public Uri bitmapToUriConverter(Bitmap mBitmap) {
   Uri uri = null;
   try {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 200, 200,
            true);
    File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "Image"
            + new Random().nextInt() + ".jpeg");
    FileOutputStream out = getActivity().openFileOutput(file.getName(),
            Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    //get absolute path
    String realPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    File f = new File(realPath);
    uri = Uri.fromFile(f);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Your Error Message", e.getMessage());
  }
return uri;
}


public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

for more details goto [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Comment: what is calculateInSampleSize ?? Please add method for it

Comment: @Anand : This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641726/decoding-bitmaps-in-android-with-the-right-size may help you, if you find proper solution then please inform.

Comment: you can ignore inSampleSize. Setting samplesize to 2 will reduce image quality by 2, as if taking only each second pixel of the image, something like that. Putting 1 or not setting this option would be ok.

Comment: i can confirm what i said about inSampleSize. Also, this method would distort image if it is not rectangular. To work with images other than rectangular, use this line `Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), true);`

Comment: This always returns null for me.

Comment: according to [this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) . creating files with `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE `is a security risk as it allows files to be read by other applications. Using it on Android N and above throws `SecurityException`

Comment: @danijax So what is your solution?

Comment: Where do you set options to bitmap??

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. For example getting thumbnail from a video in the form of a bitmap. Then we can convert the bitmap object to uri object.

```
String videoPath = mVideoUri.getEncodedPath();
System.out.println(videoPath); //prints to console the path of the saved video
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

 Uri thumbUri = getImageUri(this, thumb);
```

Comment: what's *getImageUri*?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code snippet from the [post I mentioned in my comment..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636697/get-path-and-filename-from-camera-intent-result/9067155#9067155) and it's working fine for me.

```
/**
 * Gets the last image id from the media store
 * 
 * @return
 */
private int getLastImageId() {
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
            null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "getLastImageId::id " + id);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "getLastImageId::path "
                + fullPath);
        imageCursor.close();
        return id;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

OutPut in logcat:

```
09-24 16:36:24.500: getLastImageId::id 70
09-24 16:36:24.500: getLastImageId::path /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/2012-09-24 16.36.20.jpg
```

Also I don't see any harcoded names in the above code snippet.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below Code. May be helpful to you:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            };

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                imageAdapter.images.clear();
                initializeVideoAndImage();
                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void initializeVideoAndImage() {
                final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
                String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
                Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);

                final String[] videocolumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
                Cursor videoCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, videocolumns, null, null, orderBy);
                int i = 0;
                int image_column_index = 0;

                if (imageCursor != null) {
                    image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                    int count = imageCursor.getCount();
                    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        imageCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                        int id = imageCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                        ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                        imageItem.id = id;
                        imageAdapter.images.add(imageItem);

                    }
                }

                if (videoCursor != null) {
                    image_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                    int count = videoCursor.getCount();
                    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                        int id = videoCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                        ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                        imageItem.id = id;
                        imageAdapter.images.add(imageItem);
                    }
                }
                publishProgress(i);
                if (imageCursor != null) {
                    image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                    int count = imageCursor.getCount();
                    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        imageCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                        int id = imageCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                        int dataColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        ImageItem imageItem = imageAdapter.images.get(i);
                        Bitmap img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                        int column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        imageItem.imagePath = imageCursor.getString(column_index);
                        imageItem.videoPath = "";
                        try {
                            File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image" + i);
                            imageFile.createNewFile();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                            if (bos != null && img != null) {
                                img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                            }
                            byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                            fos.write(bitmapData);
                            fos.close();
                            imageItem.thumbNailPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            try {
                                boolean cancelled = isCancelled();
                                // if async task is not cancelled, update the
                                // progress
                                if (!cancelled) {
                                    publishProgress(i);
                                    SystemClock.sleep(100);

                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                            }
                            // publishProgress();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // imageAdapter.images.add(imageItem);
                    }
                }
                imageCursor.close();

                if (videoCursor != null) {
                    image_column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                    int count = videoCursor.getCount() + i;
                    for (int j = 0; i < count; i++, j++) {
                        videoCursor.moveToPosition(j);
                        int id = videoCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                        int column_index = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                        ImageItem imageItem = imageAdapter.images.get(i);
                        imageItem.imagePath = videoCursor.getString(column_index);
                        imageItem.videoPath = imageItem.imagePath;
                        System.out.println("External : " + imageItem.videoPath);
                        try {
                            File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "imageV" + i);
                            imageFile.createNewFile();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            MediaMetadataRetriever mediaVideo = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                            mediaVideo.setDataSource(imageItem.videoPath);
                            Bitmap videoFiles = mediaVideo.getFrameAtTime();
                            videoFiles = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(videoFiles, 96, 96);
                            if (bos != null && videoFiles != null) {
                                videoFiles.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

                            }
                            byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                            fos.write(bitmapData);
                            fos.close();
                            imageItem.imagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            imageItem.thumbNailPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            try {
                                boolean cancelled = isCancelled();
                                // if async task is not cancelled, update the
                                // progress
                                if (!cancelled) {
                                    publishProgress(i);
                                    SystemClock.sleep(100);

                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                videoCursor.close();
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            };

        }.execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note : if you are using android 6.0 or greater version path will give null value.
so you have to add permission 
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

```
public void onClicked(View view){
        Bitmap bitmap=getBitmapFromView(scrollView,scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(),scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,baos);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap,"title",null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(path));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share Screenshot Using"));
    }
```