# how to open a bitmap picture in gallery in android gallery

Tags: android, database, image, uri, gallery

I want to get an `image` from database and show that in `gallery` or other apps that can show an `image`. How can set a `uri` for that `image`??

I get a image from database like this :

```
public Bitmap retrive(String table,String noeDastor,int row){
    Cursor cur=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table+" where noeDastor= '"+noeDastor+"'", null);
    cur.moveToPosition(row);
    photo=cur.getBlob(5);
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);
    Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    return theImage;
}
```

And I want show the `Image` in `gallery` of phone...

Comment: Do you have any output code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save bitmap to file. And then show in Android gallery where it has the location
if i right understand

It is a bad solution, of course, but it will work

Or check these answers

[How to get a Uri object from Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555420/how-to-get-a-uri-object-from-bitmap)

It looks like they use similar solution)