# Android : Get photo from gallery always returns bitmap not uri

Tags: android, uri, android-bitmap, android-gallery

**I call:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

startActivityForResult(intent, code);
```

**then in my ActiviyResult():**

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && data != null) {

                final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                //Get image
                Bitmap profilePicBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                  ...
```

**I try to get the uri by doing this:**

```
data.getData()
```

but it always returns null

The problem is I need the path of the bitmap on the device so I can upload it elsewhere...but I can't get the path of it without having to convert it to uri. To convert to uri you have to request permission to write external storage, see here: ([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555420/how-to-get-a-uri-object-from-bitmap](http://see%20here)) and I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it always returns null

That behavior will depend on the device and its apps.

I suspect that you will have better luck if you get rid of those undocumented extras. Presumably, rather than use an image-cropping library, you are trying to have the `ACTION_PICK` activity do the cropping. There are two problems with this:

1. There is no requirement for the `ACTION_PICK` activity to do any cropping, as those extras are not part of the Android SDK.
2. My guess is that since the cropped image does not exist as a file, they return it via the `"data"` extra (which is also outside the documented behavior of `ACTION_PICK`)

So, get rid of those extras. If you want to crop the image, [use an image-cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).