# How to get URI of image in assets folder to MainActivity? My project structure is as follwos

Tags: java, android

```
  String url = "file:///app/src/main/assets/sample.jpg";
```

Error

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/src/main/assets/sample.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:491)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:100)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:206)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:224)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:183)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get URI from bitmap?

Comment: this will help u **[How can I get URI from bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555420/how-to-get-a-uri-object-from-bitmap)**

Comment: You really have to use search before asking. Why you didn't?

Comment: What should I provide as incontext while using the method getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage)??

Comment: @SeemaBhandari `yourActivity.this`

Comment: I need this path when my application is in running state

Comment: After converting jpg image to bitmap, I used the method in this link http://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/android-getting-image-uri-from-bitmap/  but I still I am facing this issue                                                      W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/92967: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or dir

Comment: thank-you for your concern my issue was solved by referring this   link http://maulik-dhameliya.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-drawable.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load image from a assets folder you can use the assets Manager to load it

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("sample.jpg");
Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

and for more detail look it the following link
https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-assetmanager-example-to-load-image-from-assets-folder

I hope it will help you and one more thing you have also put your .properties file in java folder with classes which is also incorrect .so correct it also.
If any problem then ask again.

thanks

Comment: more specifically I need the URI of image in assets folder

Comment: InputStream is= assetManager.open("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg");

Comment: I need this path when my application is in running state

Comment: After that what should I write? plz elaborate

Comment: after this path when you get you can use it for your any purpose like if you want to show it in imageView so look at the answer convert it to bitmap and show

Comment: what you want to do with it

Comment: I need the path of this image which will be sent to server for further processing. In addition to this, server only accepts URI of any image.

Comment: this InputStream is= assetManager.open("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg"); is returning null value when assets fodler has sample.jpg in it.

Comment: Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg");

 String newPath = path.toString();

Comment: now you will have path of your image in assets

Comment: which returned java.io.FileNotFoundException: file://app/src/main/assets/sample.jpg

Comment: have you correclty set it there are three lines after "file:///" and you have set it two there

Comment: yeah I have used three lines after file: but now I am facing this issue java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/sample.jpg:

Comment: try {
            is = assetManager.open("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg");

        String newPath = path.toString();
        Log.d("imagePath",newPath);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = assetManager.open("break_icon.jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: is that android_asset or android_assets?

Comment: android_asset @SeemaBhandari

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/sample.jpg latest exception

Comment: I am getting this issue while running the application in mobile. I am trying to access the image during run-time, is that possible?

Comment: yes but have you correctly put the image in asset because i have checked it and working properly with me

Comment: yeah i have placed it .. plz check the image attached with this question..is that ok?

Comment: yes it is correct but why you are getting this error while working fine with me

Comment: currently, I am just using this code  imageURI = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio?rq=1        check this for assets setting

Comment: use this full code  Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sample.jpg"); String newPath = path.toString(); Log.d("imagePath",newPath); AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); InputStream is = null; try { is = assetManager.open("break_icon.jpg"); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

Comment: I have made asset folder by following steps given in this link

Comment: in which variable are u getting URI? path or new path?

Comment: in path is uri and newPath i have converted into string

Comment: i am getting this value file:///android_asset/sample.jpg in path

Comment: yes this is correct

Comment: now you can convert into bitmap and set into imageView or send to server.For checking set it in a imageView first.

Comment: I converted this bitmap to URI and sent it to server but now I am facing this issue java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/92972: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: external/images/media/92972 i think it is sd card path where image exist

Comment: thank-you for your concern my issue was solved by referring this   link http://maulik-dhameliya.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-drawable.html

Comment: ok you are welome