# How take a  photo without saving it?

Tags: android, android-camera

Hey i'm trying to use Android's camera without saving an image to the SD card.
I want the user to be able to take a photo (with preview), then preform some modifications to it and then choose if to save it or not.

Now in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken) question they did a work around for deleting the image after it's saved, but that dosen't seem like the right choice to me.

How can i achive this?

Isn't there a built in option for that?

Comment: I have no experience in android devel (hence why I'm posting this as a comment) but I don't think it's possible to take a picture without saving it. I mean that's the whole concept of taking a picture. Why don't you just save it as a temp file, let them modify it, and if they chose to save it save it under a filename and then delete the temp or if the chose to discard it just delete the temp. How are you supposed to edit a picture (file) when it's not saved. Alternatively you might be able to save it into the RAM of the phone...which is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a nice sample of taking an image from the camera preview without any file being created:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

do note that the image taken can be quite large , so the memory used might be very large too . you should consider sampling it in such cases .