# How to delete all pictures taken by my app in the Android gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am looking for a clean and simple way to delete all the pictures that my app put in the public gallery.

I tried this, but it does not work, while it goes in the right directory :

```
File dir =
  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null){
    for (File file : files) {
        deleteRecursively(file);
    }
}
```

Do I need a permission ? Why can't I delete the files I created in my app ?

Here is the deleteRecursively method :

```
void deleteRecursively(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()){
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()){
            deleteRecursively(child);
        }
    }
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: Do you have the Write SD Card permission?

Comment: Yes i do, I added it in the manifest

Comment: Post the deleteRecursively method.

Comment: Hi, you can check this link. This will definitely help you.http://stackoverflow.com/a/11878568/1395259 If it really helps then do upvote that.

Comment: @cleroo have you tried that method

Comment: I am gonna check it and see what it does and if it works

Comment: @cleroo Have you got the solution?

Comment: Still not ! I have an out of array with deleteLatest, because there is not any file in the repertory ^^. But I still see them in the gallery !! Haaa I am becoming crazy with that issue

Comment: @cleroo If nothing is there in folder then from where the image is coming to gallery?? Sorry, but nothing is magic in development. Can you please check each and every directory once again?

Comment: Maybe it takes a little time for the gallery to be updated ? Should I delete all the files in a ASyncTask ? I'm thinking about doing so

Comment: I tried to do that in an AsyncTask, with a progress bar. My code says how many files it finds, and how many it actually deletes. And this is the answer :  `found : 3 files. deleted :0 files`.

Comment: Maybe it's about clearing cache ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the deleteRecursively() method to:

```
void deleteRecursively(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()){
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()){
            deleteRecursively(child);
        }
    } else {
        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add uses permission in manifest file `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

Comment: I added it before you told me, thanks anyway, but is does not work

Comment: `File dir =
  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null){
    for (File file : files) {
        file.delete();
    }
}` is enough :)

Comment: No it is not, my pictures are still in the gallery ! Or maybe there are just the thumbnails ?

Comment: They are not in the file system (in `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/` and `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`. But I still see them in the gallery.

Comment: @cleroo If you are passing camera intent, then image file goes only inside the Camera folder. You can check in MyFiles/DCIM/Camera

Comment: Strange, I still see the pictures in the gallery.

Comment: Probably, due to thumbnail cache, the gallery still shows you the pictures. Refreshing the gallery or clearing thumbnail cache will do the trick.