# capturing images with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, capture

I am capturing images using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. it is working fine in most of the devices. but it is not working correctly in some latest android device as expected.

my intention is capture image using camera and send it to the server but not to store that image in default gallery of the device.

****: When i capture image, it is returning some other gallery image in onActivityResult method instead of captured image in some latest android devices.
I am using below code to capture and store images.

```
public void launchCamera(View v) {
    Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST );
}
```

In onActivityResult method,

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, BaseColumns._ID, };
            Cursor c = null;
            Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            try {
                if (u != null) {
                    c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
                }
                if ((c != null) && (c.moveToLast())) {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = getBitMapFromLocalPath(c.getString(2), 3);
                    idsImagesgot.add(thumbnail);
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    cr.delete( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(3), null);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
```

Can any one help me out in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Sathish

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Photos taken by the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE are not registered in the MediaStore automatically on all devices.

The official Android guide gives that example:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive
But that does not work either on all devices.

The only reliable method I am aware of consists in saving the path to the picture in a local variable. Beware that your app may get killed while in background (while the camera app is running), so you must save the path during onSaveInstanceState.

Edit after comment:

Create a temporary file name where the photo will be stored when starting the intent.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");
fileName = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

`fileName` is a String, a field of your activity. You must save it that way:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
{
 super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
 bundle.putString("fileName", fileName);
}
```

and recover it in onCreate():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 if (savedInstanceState != null)
  fileName = savedInstanceState.getString("fileName");
 // ...
}
```

Now, at the time of onActivityResult, you know the name of the file where the photo was stored (`fileName`). You can do anything you wish with it, and then delete it.

2013-09-19 edit: It seems that some camera apps ignore the putExtra uri, and store the pic in a different place. So, before using the value of `fileName` you should check whether the intent is null or not. If you get a non-null intent, then you should prefer `intent.getData()` over `fileName`. Use `fileName` as a backup solution only when it is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Remi, Can you please guide me any feasible way that meets my requirements i stated above, if possible?

Comment: Hi Remi, thanks for your code. i am using the same above and providing URI to the capture intent and after saving my image into server i am deleting that temparory image but the image is still available in default gallery.. can you pls suggest me the way i need to delete file from default gallery.

Comment: How do you delete the file? Something like `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);` should work, I suppose.

Comment: Also, this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken

Comment: What is `PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE` in the sixth line of the first paragraph of code?

Comment: PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE is a user-defined constant. You can define it to any value you like: `private static final int PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;`.

Answer (score 4):

My onActivityResult() method looks like this and it works in obtaining the image from **MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return a thumbnail, not the real image.

Comment: @Markust  Look at the user's original question carefully.  In his code he is intending to obtain the thumbnail.

Comment: @Igor, despite what OP's intentions are, might you be able to show a solution that returns the full size image? That would be very helpful indeed. thx