# RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, firebase-storage

I want to **upload image to Firebase** after capturing by **Camera**, But getting an error saying "**Failure delivering result**". Configuration of Firebase is all perfect. Just after capturing the image and while I click on proceed app Crashing.

This is my **ActivityMain.Java**:

```
package com.example.intuition.firebase;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    public Button mUpload;
    public ImageView mImageView;
    private static final int CAMERA_REUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            mProgress.setMessage("Uploading...");
            mProgress.show();

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(mImageView);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.example.intuition.firebase, PID: 4694
                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.intuition.firebase/com.example.intuition.firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3592)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3635)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                             at com.example.intuition.firebase.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:57)
                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5535)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3588)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3635) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1390) 
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like data is null. Do a null check before accessing data.?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982184/camera-activity-returning-null-android)

Comment: You mean, App is not taking the path of that captured image ?

Comment: Can u debug and tell me whether data is null or not?

Comment: This may help u to capture image using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952859/capturing-images-with-mediastore-action-image-capture-intent-in-android

Comment: check your setResult