# The code is capturing image but it is not showing in my image viewer

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEbRU.png), and I have no idea why it is crashing.

[This is the image of my code in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aChfK.png). I'm not having any error or warning that could make my app crash, but it is still crashing.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace or anything else for us?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952859/capturing-images-with-mediastore-action-image-capture-intent-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952859/capturing-images-with-mediastore-action-image-capture-intent-in-android) i think this is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should consider adding

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
```

to your if condition bellow the `onActivityResult` .

Comment: thank you it worked but it is still not showing me captured image image in my image viewer

Comment: the rest of your code is not showing in the screenshots so we could help more.

Comment: the code is that much only but i have added my xml files snippet in the question itself