# Problems with picture uploading

Tags: android, encoding, picturegallery

I have this activity in which the user can either choose one image from Gallery or just take a picture and (along with other data) upload it to a website.

So far I've encountered 2 different problems:

**1)** If I try it with a picture from the gallery, I get an IOException with message 
    /external/images/media/2305: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
That happens when it comes to open the file stream.

**2)** If I try it by taking the picture, it goes ok, but the encoded data string is composed of "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" (really longer, but only A's) and I guess that's not a good sign. This is only a guess since I still cannot properly upload it to the website, but different pictures showing the same data string just smells funny.

The code here

```
@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            loadImage(imageUri);

    }
    break;
case SELECT_PHOTO:
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){  
        imageUri = data.getData();
        loadImage(imageUri);
    }
}
}
```

This is how I load the image (either pic taken or from the gallery) onto the ImageView. It works ok.

```
public void loadImage(Uri selectedImage){
    mActivity.getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

    ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

        ivPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mActivity.croutonInfo(selectedImage.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        mActivity.croutonAlert("Failed to load");
        e("Camera " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the method I use to mock the data upload. When I get the API it will have an asynctask to deal with the http transfer, so far it only puts the data into a logicless transfer object

```
public void uploadTapa() throws IOException{
    mActivity.croutonInfo("subiendo tapa ");
    d("uploadTapa new ");
    TapaUploadParametros tup = new TapaUploadParametros();
    d("uploadTapa bar: " + nombreBar);
    tup.setBarNombre(etBarName.getText().toString());
    d("uploadTapa tapa: " + nombreTapa);
    tup.setNombre(etTapaName.getText().toString());
    d("uploadTapa municipio: " + municipio);
    tup.setLocalidad(municipio);
    d("uploadTapa provincia: " + provincia);
    tup.setProvincia(provincia);
    d("uploadTapa tipologiaId: " + tipologiaId);
    tup.setTipo(tipologiaId);
    d("uploadTapa precioId: " + precioId);
    tup.setPrecio(precioId);

    String encodedImage = encodeImgForHTTP(imageUri);
    d("uploadTapa encoded image: " + encodedImage);
    tup.setPic(encodedImage);
    d("uploadTapa direccionBar: " + direccionBar);
    tup.setBarDireccion(direccionBar);
}
```

And this is the method to encode the image for http transfer. Images from gallery fail just after "before opening stream"

```
   private String encodeImgForHTTP (Uri imageUri) throws IOException{
        ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();
        d("encodeImgForHTTP before opening stream ");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageUri.getPath());
        d("encodeImgForHTTP after opening stream ");
        // Get binary bytes for encode
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        d("encodeImgForHTTP after getting byte array ");
        // base 64 encode for text transmission (HTTP)
        d("encodeImgForHTTP pre 64: " + imageBytes);
        String data_string = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE); 
        d("encodeImgForHTTP before returning the encoded data string " + data_string);
        return data_string;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong with the gallery images? Why does the encoding of different pictures look the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I finally got it to work. First I used Emil's advice and saved the image. DCIM_PATH is the path to the DCIM folder.

```
public void takePhoto() {
    String directoryPath = DCIM_PATH;
    d("takePhoto directoryPath: " + directoryPath);
    this.pictureFileName = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
    String filePath = directoryPath + pictureFileName ;
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    if (!directory.exists()) { // in case there's no DCIM folder
        directory.mkdirs(); // just create it
    }
    d("takePhoto filePath: " + filePath);
    this.imageUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
    d("takePhoto imageUri: " + filePath);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // here's where I tell the intent where to save the file
    intent.putExtra( 
            MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile( new File(filePath) )
            );

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

}
```

I had to use two different methods for loading the picture to the imageview. If it's a picture just taken, I use this one:

```
public void loadImageJustTaken(Uri selectedImage) {
    mActivity.getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

    Bitmap bitmap = 
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath());

    ivPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But to use one from the gallery I have to use the contentResolver

```
public void loadImage(Uri selectedImage){

    imageUri = selectedImage;
    mActivity.getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

    ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                .getBitmap(cr, imageUri);

        ivPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        ivPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mActivity.croutonInfo(imageUri.getPath());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e("Camera " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

When I want to upload the image, I have to encode it. This method works as long as you provide it with the right file path

```
  private String encodeImgForHTTP (Uri imageUri) throws IOException{
    String realPicPath = getPath(imageUri);
    d("encodeImgForHTTP before opening stream " + realPicPath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(realPicPath);
    d("encodeImgForHTTP after opening stream ");
    // Get binary bytes for encode
    byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
    d("encodeImgForHTTP after getting byte array ");

    // base 64 encode for text transmission (HTTP)
    //String data_string = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    d("encodeImgForHTTP pre 64: " + imageBytes);
    String data_string = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE); 
    d("encodeImgForHTTP before returning the encoded data string " + data_string);
    return data_string;
}
```

And here's how I get the "real path" for the picture:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = mActivity.
            managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null){ // with pictures just taken, the uri returned by the onActivityResult makes cursor to be null. Following method takes care of that
        uri = saveMediaEntry(imageUri.getPath(), pictureFileName, "");
        d("cursor nulo, segundo cursor con uri " + uri.getPath());
        cursor = mActivity.
                managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    }
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

The method saveMediaEntry creates an entry to the device's media database returning its Uri. Using that Uri, the cursor now will point to the picture file we want

```
  private Uri saveMediaEntry(
        String imagePath,String title,String description) throws IOException {

    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);

    ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
    v.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
    v.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
    v.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    v.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME));
    //v.put(Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateTaken) ;
    v.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    v.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
    File f = new File(imagePath) ;
    File parent = f.getParentFile() ;
    String path = parent.toString().toLowerCase() ;
    String name = parent.getName().toLowerCase() ;
    v.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, path.hashCode());
    v.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    v.put(Images.Media.SIZE,f.length()) ;
    f = null ;

    v.put(Images.Media.LATITUDE, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE));
    v.put(Images.Media.LONGITUDE, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE));

    v.put("_data",imagePath) ;
    ContentResolver c = mActivity.getContentResolver() ;
    return c.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, v);
}
```

After all this, pictures get loaded OK, and the Base64.encodeToString returns are different for different pictures :)

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: any idea about my question? (sort of similar to this one ) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req

Answer (score 1):

I think you should buffer your input stream into smaller byte arrays, and not use the `available` function as it is an estimate, in your encoding function, to start with.

In order to take a picture you have to determine a path where you would like the image saved and pass that as an extra in the intent, for example:

```
private void capture(){
    String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "/";
    String filePath = directoryPath+Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    this.capturePath = filePath; // you will process the image from this path if the capture goes well
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile( new File(filePath) ) );
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAPTURE);                

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm more than sure (since I'm completely green at encoding files and such) that there's lot of room for improvement there. I just wanted to achieve it using native resources, since most examples I found used external libraries from apache and the like (and I'm already using quite a few in this app).

About the pictures: do I need to save the image to upload it? Isn't valid the temporary uri I get from the camera intent?

Comment: @Frank I don't recall any temporary URI from the camera intent but I will tell you that there is a lot inconsistencies with this capture behavior between devices. For example here an issue I ran into when trying to implement it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken/8555925#8555925

Comment: I'm trying this snippet and now it won't respond to my pressing "check" after shooting the pic. The screen remains on the pic taken. It does work if I press on "X" to cancel and go back to my activity...

Comment: any idea about my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req