# How to save image and video captured from camera in App internal memory only in Android?

Tags: android, video-capture, android-gallery, android-image

I am working on a project where I need to save images and videos in application internal memory only (not in SDCard or device Gallery). I am using below code. But this also save the image/video to device gallery. Please advice.

```
Bitmap bm;
        View v=imageview;
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bm=Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        String fileName="image.png";        
        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I want to make the image and video private and secured. So I want to save them in apps internal memory. So no other app can access it. Please suggest.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741

Comment: i dont understand. what do you mean by apps internal memory(not in sdcard or device gallery)? could you please tell me.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy This provide the mechanism to save the image in device SDCard. So all apps can access it. I want to make the image and video private and secured. So I want to save them in apps internal memory. So no other app can access it. Please suggest.

Comment: look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: What type of device are you testing with? I know from experience that HTC pulls ALL images stored on the phone into the gallery, so you'll have to create your own method to delete it from the gallery in that specific case.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the images in internal memory, it will store the image on internal images folder.

```
                    Uri uriSavedImage;

                // the temp folder to start the camera activity with
                    String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum)+ ".png";
                    path = getDir("images", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).getPath() + "/" + fileName;
                    // start the camera activity
                    file = new File(path);
                    while (file.exists()) {
                        imageNum++;
                        fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum)+ ".png";     
                        path = getDir("images_pho",Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).getPath()+ "/" + fileName;
                        file = new File(path);
                    }
                    Uri ur = Uri.parse(file.toString());
                    uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            OutputStream imageFileOS;
            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

hope its helps

Comment: I checked the code. But it is also going to device gallery. Can't we make it to save at a place where none other app can access it.

Comment: you checked with device or emulator?

Comment: I checked it in device.

Comment: device having internal memory accessible now a days mobile cofiguration... so where ever you took image it will so in the gallery... olden days mobile it s not accessible.. if i get a solution means i will tel u!

Answer (score 0):

As I told you, you can store the picture taken from the camera in the internal storage and immediately you can delete the taken image from the gallery with `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);` or you can use this :

```
if (takenpicturefile.exists())
        if (takenpicturefile.delete())
            Log.d("tag","filedeleted");
```

Fore more details, you might need to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken). Hope it helps.