# How to save the catured image in application's internal memory

Tags: android, android-camera

I have captured image through camera intent and image are saved to internal memory.But my images are also stored in gallary .I don't want to save the images into gallary for private purpose.
Here is my code:-

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream1;
            try {
                mFileOutStream1 = openFileOutput("IMG" + counter + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                photo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutStream1);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
         // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

       // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Hope this help you..!!!

Comment: I implemented this code now,but in this also images are stored in gallary.Can u help me that how to delete image from gallary.

Comment: I am thinking that image will capture then it will save into internal memory and only then image will be deleted from gallary .

Comment: can u please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken

Comment: I am not getting how to delete images from gallary .

Comment: check this http://vijaykherandroidblog.blogspot.in/2012/02/delete-image-from-gallery-capture-using.html

Comment: Thanks a lot i have deleted images from gallary .