# Android camera with intent save discard option

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

In android, if I open a camera with an intent is there any way of ensuring that I have the option to save or discard the photo or would I have to use the camera class for this?

Thank for the help

Comment: I could not understand what exactly you want but check this link if you find something relevant your requirement, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken

Comment: @RonakJoshi, Thanks for your response. This is not what I was asking. I will give you an example if use an intent to start the camera activity when taking a photo on Nexus 4, after the picture is taken a dialog comes up with a tick or a cross so you can choose to save or discard the photo. On a Galaxy S5 however the dialog does not appear the images is automatically saved. I was wondering if there was a way to ensure the save discard dialog appears whenever you use an intent to start the camera activity.